# How to remove duplicates links if keyword appears multiple times in a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to find a keyword from a webpage using a spider (web crawler) that stores the matching keyword against the URL link in a csv file. But the issue is if a keyword appears multiple times on the same page, then there is duplication in the csv file. How do I remove duplicate links against a keyword?

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjaXP.jpg)

```
allowed_domains = ["www.geo.tv"]
start_urls = ["https://www.geo.tv/"]
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback="check_buzzwords")]

crawl_count = 0
words_found = 0                                 

def check_buzzwords(self, response):

    self.__class__.crawl_count += 1

    crawl_count = self.__class__.crawl_count

    wordlist = [
        "Imran",
        "Hello",
        "Nauman",
        ]
    

    url = response.url
    contenttype = response.headers.get("content-type", "").decode('utf-8').lower()
    data = response.body.decode('utf-8')

    for word in wordlist:
            substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
            for pos in substrings:
                    ok = False
                    if not ok:
                            self.__class__.words_found += 1
                            print(word + ";" + url + ";")
    return Item()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what your asking, but it sounds like all you need to do is to stop iterating the full iterable returned by `find_all_substrings`.  Just `break` after the first one since you know all the additional iterations will be duplicates.

for example:

```
for word in wordlist:
    substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
    for pos in substrings:
        self.__class__.words_found += 1
        print(word + ";" + url + ";")
        break
```